# Foreach array and use array member in callback

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I have array of remote files address. I simply use for in to foreach array and in body of foreach, I starting HTTP GET request for data download. But everything is async and I need to know filename to save the file in request callback.

What is the best practice to solve this?

Demo code:

```
files = ["url.com/file.png", "url.com/file.doc"]

for file in files
  req = http.get file, (response) =>
    response.setEncoding 'binary'
    body = ""

    response.on "data", (chunk) =>
      body += chunk

    response.on "end", () =>
      #Here I needs to know the file name to save it
      fs.writeFileSync @currentFolder + "/Files/" + file, body, "binary"
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's the problem? Are you asking how to convert `url.com/file.png` to `file.png`?

Comment: No, on line with writeFileSync I needs to get value of original variable "file". But everything is async, so variable "file" will be filled only with last filename.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought coffeescript for loops used closures to prevent this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to scope it. Use a function like this:

```
files = ["url.com/file.png", "url.com/file.doc"]

for file in files
    ((file) ->
        req = http.get file, (response) =>
            response.setEncoding 'binary'
            body = ""

        response.on "data", (chunk) =>
            body += chunk

        response.on "end", () =>
            fs.writeFileSync @currentFolder + "/Files/" + file, body, "binary"
    ).call @, file
```

Comment: Why not use `do`? See the bottom of this section: http://coffeescript.org/#loops

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this in CoffeeScript is with a `do` call. Also setting the encoding to `'binary'` makes no sense and just creates extra work to convert the data back and forth from a Buffer and a string.

```
for file in files
  do (file) =>
    req = http.get file, (response) =>
      parts = []

      response.on "data", (chunk) =>
        parts.push chunk

      response.on "end", () =>
        body = Buffer.concat parts
        fs.writeFileSync @currentFolder + "/Files/" + file, body
```